# Have a share button IoS with all possible entities

Tags: ios, iphone, share, social-media

I am looking for a share button with all entities like FB/G+/Watsapp/Mail etc., So effectively, once the user presses the share button, a popup with all values should turn up and upon selection of the appropriate item, it should share accordingly.

Can anyone please guide through the steps to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes in your viewDidLoad:

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                            target:self
                            action:@selector(compartir:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
```

And define your selector method to be called as action (in my case named as "compartir"):

```
- (void) compartir:(id)sender{

//Si no


NSLog(@"shareButton pressed");


NSString *stringtoshare= @"This is a string to share";
UIImage *imagetoshare = img; //This is an image to share.

NSArray *activityItems = @[stringtoshare, imagetoshare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]                initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,       UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answer for your query:[Answer for activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26986845/2098690)

You need to use activity view controller for showing all possibilities which iphone can Give.